# Programming a function to show possible finishes in Darts game

Tags: r, math

I am currently trying to program a function that shows me possible ways to finish a certain number of points in 1 to 3 dart throws. Only the range from 170 to 2 points is necessary.

Example: I have 120 points left. I want a function that gives out possible ways to finish 120 points. For example by throwing 40 - 40 - 40; 60 - 60 or 57 - 57 - 6 and so on...

I am new to programming in R and to programming in general and have absolutely no idea how and where to start. Does anyone have a recommendation for me? Is there a specific function that can be applied in this case?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

here is another approach. One thing you would have to fix (if needed), this solution makes separate 'solutions` for, let's say, a single 2, and a double 1.

so, 4 can be ended with
single 1, single 1, double 2
single 2, double 2
double 2, double 2
and this gets worse on the thee dart finishes...

```
singles <- c(1:20, 25)
doubles <- 2 * singles
triples <- 3*1:20

#all possible eidings
one.dart <- tidyr::crossing( first = doubles )
two.dart <- tidyr::crossing( first = unique( c(singles, doubles, triples ) ),
                             second = doubles )
three.dart <- tidyr::crossing( first = unique( c( singles, doubles, triples ) ),
                               second = unique( c( singles, doubles, triples ) ),
                               third = doubles )
#bind together
DT <- rbindlist( list( one.dart, two.dart, three.dart), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
#calculate finish total and number of darts used
DT[, finish := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE) ]
DT[, darts := rowSums( !is.na(.SD)), .SDcols = 1:3 ]

calculate_finish <- function( x ) {
  DT[ finish == x, 1:3]
}

calculate_finish( 120 )
#      first second third
#   1:    10     60    50
#   2:    13     57    50
#   3:    16     54    50
#   4:    19     51    50
#   5:    20     50    50
# ---                   
# 130:    60     40    20
# 131:    60     42    18
# 132:    60     48    12
# 133:    60     50    10
# 134:    60     54     6
```

Comment: this is absolutely amazing! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Now I have got another question: when I try to execute the command one.dart <- tidyr::crossing( first = doubles ) I get the following error:
"Fehler in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  es gibt kein Paket namens ‘lifecycle’" ...do you know why this error comes up? I already updated R Studio to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

the question you have is rather general - more like outsouring your programming than finding help for specific implementation parts of the code. Anyhow here goes a simplified solution that is far from perfect programming wise but does the job. I hope it helps you to understand progamming and functions plus a bit of R, given that you have a specific problem.

```
# we need this library to be able to use the %>% operator below
library(dplyr)
# vector of all the possible field numbers (i have no idea but you can look them up and fill the field)
dboard <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
# expand this to a grid of all possible combinations 
all_combinations <- expand.grid(dboard, dboard,dboard ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# your function with two inputs
get_throw_combinations <- function(remaining_points, throws){
  # call the outside of the functions defined possible combinations
  res <- all_combinations %>% 
    # select from first to number of trows columns
    dplyr::select(1:throws) %>%
    # reduce reduncancy (happens when throws < 3)
    dplyr::distinct() %>% 
    # filter those where the rowsum is equal to the target
    dplyr::filter(rowSums(.) == remaining_points)
  # return the result
  return (res)
}
# run your function for 5 points with two throws
get_throw_combinations(5, 2)
# results R will display
  Var1 Var2
1    4    1
2    3    2
3    2    3
4    1    4
```

Comment: I only expected something like "maybe try this or that function" but wow, the help you guys offer here is amazing!! Thank you very much! R offers a vast amount of different functions and I feel quite overwhelmed but this sure will help me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force approach using `expand.grid` + `subset`

```
v <- 2:170
res <- lapply(
  1:3,
  function(k) subset(u <- expand.grid(rep(list(v), k)), rowSums(u) == 120)
)
```